# Lagged Dependents

Tags: forecasting

I am in a scenario where I am trying to forecast 2014 call volume in a call center based on prior call volumes in 2013 and 2012.  How do I difference 2014 call volume, and how do I lag 2012 and 2013 call volume so that I can run a statistically sound model?  Also I have access to data on these call volumes by week and by day, is not by day a better choice than by week?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to model daily data and the roll the forecasts upto weekly/monthly/quarterly/annual projections. You will need to incorporate day-of-the-week effects; week-of-the-year effects; month-of-the-year effects; level shifts ; local time trends ; holiday effects around each of the knowm holidays and special events and any needed ARIMA structure while taking into account unusual values/changes in parameters over time and changes in error variance over time. You might want to look at http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/news/47-can-forecasting-help-me-staff-a-specific-call-center- for some guidance. In terms or transparency I was one of the developers of AUTOBOX.

Comment: +1 The comments in the "preview" [linked through your reference](http://demand-planning.com/2010/03/18/can-forecasting-help-me-staff-a-specific-hewlett-packard-call-center-at-1030-am-on-a-friday/) directly address this question: one comment addresses how to use a forecasting model for managing the call center and the other explains why having a good model (that accounts for the factors you mention here) is important.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an R user, the [timeSeries package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeSeries/index.html) provides functions for lagging and differencing time series.